# Optimizing ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize this query that sorts `posts` by `reputation` field (1st) and then `id` field (2nd). Without 1st field query takes ~0.250sec, but with it takes up to ~2.500sec (means 10x times slower, terrible). Any suggestion?

```
SELECT -- everything is ok here
FROM posts AS p
ORDER BY 
    -- 1st: sort by reputation if exists (1 reputation = 1 day)
    (CASE WHEN p.created_at >= unix_timestamp(now() - INTERVAL p.reputation DAY) 
        THEN +p.reputation ELSE NULL END) DESC, -- also used 0 instead of NULL
    -- 2nd: sort by id dec
    p.id DESC
WHERE p.status = 'published' -- the only thing for filter
LIMIT 0,10 -- limit provided as well
```

Notes: 
- Using InnoDB (MySQL 5.7.19)
- Primary is `id` on `posts` table
- Fields are indexed both `created_at` and `reputation`

Explain result:

```
# id,  select_type, table, partitions, type,  possible_keys, key,  key_len, ref,  rows,    filtered, Extra
# '1', 'SIMPLE',    'p',   NULL,       'ALL', NULL,          NULL, NULL,    NULL, '31968', '100.00', 'Using filesort'
```

**UPDATE^^**

Reputation provides that: A post, how many (n=reputation) day could be shown on the top of list.

Actually, I was trying to give reputations to some posts that could be fetched on the top of list, and find that solution: [Order posts by "rep" but only for "one" day limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749033/order-posts-by-rep-but-only-for-one-day-limit). But after some time (about 2 years) that solution became a problem now due of increased volume of table data. If I can not resolve this, then I should remove that feature from the service.

**UPDATE^^**

```
-- all date's are unix timestamp (bigint)
SELECT p.*
    , u.name user_name, u.status user_status
    , c.name city_name, t.name town_name, d.name dist_name
    , pm.meta_name, pm.meta_email, pm.meta_phone
    -- gets last comment as json
    , (SELECT concat("{", 
        '"id":"', pc.id, '",', 
        '"content":"', replace(pc.content, '"', '\\"'), '",', 
        '"date":"', pc.date, '",', 
        '"user_id":"', pcu.id, '",', 
        '"user_name":"', pcu.name, '"}"') last_comment_json 
        FROM post_comments pc 
        LEFT JOIN users pcu ON (pcu.id = pc.user_id) 
        WHERE pc.post_id = p.id
        ORDER BY pc.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_comment
FROM posts p
    -- no issues with these
    LEFT JOIN users u ON (u.id = p.user_id)
    LEFT JOIN citys c ON (c.id = p.city_id)
    LEFT JOIN towns t ON (t.id = p.town_id)
    LEFT JOIN dists d ON (d.id = p.dist_id)
    LEFT JOIN post_metas pm ON (pm.post_id = p.id)
WHERE p.status = 'published'
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY 
    -- everything okay until here
    -- any other indexed fields makes query slow, not just "case" part
    (CASE WHEN p.created_at >= unix_timestamp(now() - INTERVAL p.reputation DAY) 
        THEN +p.reputation ELSE NULL END) DESC, 
    -- only id field (primary) is effective, no other indexes 
    p.id DESC
LIMIT 0,10;
```

Explain;

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, PRIMARY, p, , ref, PRIMARY,user_id,status,reputation,created_at,city_id-town_id-dist_id,title-content, status, 1, const, 15283, 100.00, Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
# dunno, these join's are not using, but if i remove returning fields from select part show "Using index condition"
1, PRIMARY, u, , eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 2, p.user_id, 1, 100.00, 
1, PRIMARY, c, , eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 1, p.city_id, 1, 100.00, 
1, PRIMARY, t, , eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 2, p.town_id, 1, 100.00, 
1, PRIMARY, d, , eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 2, p.dist_id, 1, 100.00, 
1, PRIMARY, pp, , eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 2, p.id, 1, 100.00, 
2, DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, pc, , ref, post_id,visibility,status, post_id, 2, func, 2, 67.11, Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
2, DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, pcu, , eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 2, pc.user_id, 1, 100.00,
```

Comment: No index can be used to order by a CASE statement. Can you explain the logic of that CASE statement?

Comment: Hi @Paul, thanks for replying. I've updated my question.

Comment: While not a perfect solution in terms of set theory, you could just run a procedure/event once a day that sets the reputation (or a copy of that field if you want to keep the original reputation) to 0 when its lifetime has ended. You can also find similar orderings that can be modelled with an index, but for your specific formula (the hard cutoff at end of "lifetime" and switch to id; and that a post with rep 100 will always be ordered infront of one with rep 99, even if the rep100-post has been shown for the last 90 days already), I don't see (at least on first sight) an indexable formula.

Comment: Hey, I thought of it, using a cron-like tool. But seems the problem is related something different. Because, even each field in order by clause already indexed, when I give second field to order by, then app is going to slow down. Couldn't figure out.

Comment: If `id` is your primary key, and you do not have anything in your `where`-clause, `order by newreputationcolumn desc, id desc` should work fine. Otherwise you would need a composite index on `(newreputationcolumn, id)`. If that doesn't work, add the explain output. The important thing is that you do not order by a derived value (which you don't do if you just write "0" in there using the event/cronjob instead of calculation it on the fly).

Comment: There is no need for cron, as an extra column "p.created_at + INTERVAL p.reputation DAY" only needs to be set once (or on each reputation change) and will yield the order needed. Waiting for EXPLAIN for the rest...

Comment: With your new `where`-clause, you would need an index on `(status, newreputation, id)` (or without id). You can test if it would work if you use `(status, reputation, id)` and use `order by reputation desc, id desc)`. It will have the new speed, but the incorrect order (until you write 0 in that or a new column).

Comment: @peufeu If I understand the op correctly, you cannot just use `p.created_at + INTERVAL p.reputation DAY`, as it would not do the "cutoff" at the end of the lifetime. It would just be ordered as if it had been posted later. Currently, the moment the lifetime runs out, it will jump back to the place it had if it didn't have any reputation (which could be the action taken by a cronjob). Also, a post with reputation 100 will currently be infront of a post with rep 99 until the rep runs out; using the formula, a 99 rep post posted today will be placed infront of a 100 rep post posted 3 days ago.

Comment: (All that assuming that the behaviour should not change. Other kind of orderings can of course be implemented with such a formula, and maybe just changing the exact behaviour might be a good solution too. And maybe there even is a formula for this situation, but at least on first sight, I didn't find one to express that condition).

Comment: Hmmm you're right, it'd need a cron... Not a problem if the number of lines to be updated is small though, usually the number of stickies and such isn't that high...

Comment: Okay, question is updated. PS: Without join or other stuff, "case" clause doesn't affect query performance, even with a few field more in order by part.

Comment: Well, `GROUP BY p.id` makes it a completely different query - which explains why nothing we proposed here had any effect. Fortunately you don't need it, so remove it. If any of your tables are not 1:1 (maybe post_meta, it's not listed in your explain), join them later (after the resultset is limited to 10 rows), or completely remove it for testing for now. Create the index `(status, reputation, id)`. Replace `order by case` with `order by reputation desc, id desc` (just a test to see the speed effect, until you e.g. do the cronjob or use a different order method). And post with explain.

Comment: I made it as you said creating new index and ordering by your way, but chance.

Comment: Anyway, I am giving up. I would like thank you all, cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very interesting query. During its optimisation you may discover and understand a lot of new information about how MySQL works. I am not sure that I will have time to write everything in details at once, but I can gradually update.

## Why it is slow

There are basically two scenarios: a *quick* and a *slow*.

In a *quick* scenario you are walking in some predefined order over a table and probably at the same time quickly fetch some data by id for each row from other tables. It this case you stop walking as soon as you have enough rows specified by your LIMIT clause. Where does the order come from? From a b-tree index that you have on the table or the order of a result set in a subquery.

In a *slow* scenario you do not have that predefined order, and MySQL has to implicitly put all data into a temporary table, sort the table on some field and return the *n* rows from your LIMIT clause. If any of the fields that you put into that temporary table is of type TEXT (not VARCHAR), MySQL does not even try to keep that table in RAM and flushes and sorts it on disk (hence additional IO processing).

## First thing to fix

There are many situations when you can not build an index that will allow you to follow its order (when you ORDER BY columns from different tables, for example), so the rule of thumb in such situations is to minimise the data that MySQL will put in the temporary table. How can you do it? You select only identifiers of the rows in a subquery and after you have the ids, you join the ids to the table itself and other tables to fetch the content. That is you make a small table with an order and then use the quick scenario. (This slightly contradicts to SQL in general, but each flavor of SQL has its own means to optimise queries that way).

Coincidentally, your `SELECT -- everything is ok here` looks funny, since it is the first place where it is not ok.

```
SELECT p.*
    , u.name user_name, u.status user_status
    , c.name city_name, t.name town_name, d.name dist_name
    , pm.meta_name, pm.meta_email, pm.meta_phone
    , (SELECT concat("{", 
        '"id":"', pc.id, '",', 
        '"content":"', replace(pc.content, '"', '\\"'), '",', 
        '"date":"', pc.date, '",', 
        '"user_id":"', pcu.id, '",', 
        '"user_name":"', pcu.name, '"}"') last_comment_json 
        FROM post_comments pc 
        LEFT JOIN users pcu ON (pcu.id = pc.user_id) 
        WHERE pc.post_id = p.id
        ORDER BY pc.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_comment
FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM posts p
    WHERE p.status = 'published'
    ORDER BY 
        (CASE WHEN p.created_at >= unix_timestamp(now() - INTERVAL p.reputation DAY) 
            THEN +p.reputation ELSE NULL END) DESC, 
        p.id DESC
    LIMIT 0,10
) ids
JOIN posts p ON ids.id = p.id  -- mind the join for the p data
LEFT JOIN users u ON (u.id = p.user_id)
LEFT JOIN citys c ON (c.id = p.city_id)
LEFT JOIN towns t ON (t.id = p.town_id)
LEFT JOIN dists d ON (d.id = p.dist_id)
LEFT JOIN post_metas pm ON (pm.post_id = p.id)
;
```

That is the first step, but even now you can see that you do not need to make these useless LEFT JOINS and json serialisations for the rows you do not need. (I skipped `GROUP BY p.id`, because I do not see which LEFT JOIN might result in several rows, you do not do any aggregation).

yet to write about:

- indexes
- reformulate CASE clause (use UNION ALL)
- probably forcing an index

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking your time. That was really magical, thank you! :) As you said, I suppose I learnt so much about how MySQL works.
Before: without any p.reputation stuff sort, but only p.id, 5 qry; `(0.286+0.286+0.283+0.287+0.247) / 5 = 0.277sec`
After: with the solution you addressed with p.reputation stuff and and p.id sort, 5 qry; `(0.399+0.328+0.348+0.329+0.340) / 5 = 0.348sec`.BTW, joins are affecting the query about 0.130sec. I thought of to put everything once on the posts table, but it sounds unprofessional while working with a relational database. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

- "ORDER BY expression": the expression has to be computed for each row in the table, then the sort done on the whole table, then the results go through the LIMIT.
- No index use: "ORDER BY col" when "col" is part of an index can eliminate the sort by going through the index in-order. This is very efficient when using LIMIT. However, it will not work here.

There are ways out of this mess, but you will need to tell how many different levels of "reputation" you have (like 3, or like "a lot") and how they are statistically distributed (like, 1 user with reputation 100 and the rest all have zero, or evenly distributed).

**EDIT**

Hmm, no information on the statistical distribution of "reputation" or its possible range of values. In this case, let's go with the blunt approach:

Let's add a column "repdate" which contains:

```
repdate = p.created_at + INTERVAL p.reputation DAY
```

This corresponds to shifting posts one day into the future for each reputation point they have. They will then sort accordingly. Adjust to taste if p.created_at is not a DATETIME.

Now, we can simply "ORDER BY repdate DESC" and with an index on it, it will be fast.

Comment: Hi @peufeu, thanks for replying. I've updated my question.

Comment: Actually, seems like same solution, also I tried that part in "select" phase, not just in "order by". As you said, the problem is computation for each row. But interestingly, even given field is indexed already, app going crazy when I add second field to `order by` clause, couldn't understand.

Comment: what is the exact sql query that goes crazy?

Comment: Everything is okay until order by (with one-field clause), but if I add any second field to order by (doesn't matter, "case" stuff in question or anything, else that already indexed) then it is going to slow down noticeable.

Comment: can you post query and results of EXPLAIN?

Comment: The problem here is that the exclusion is based on repdate, the sorting on reputation. Perhaps the sorting on repdate would also bei helpfull? Or can you drop the exclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an index with columns: `id`, `reputation`, `created_at` could help to speed up a bit, That would be the easiest solution, if you did not try that yet. The DBMS would not have to read so much data, to calculate the offset, limit - affected records.

Comment: Hi @aschoerk, thanks for replying. I've updated my question.

Comment: The quick solution could help. You have no concatenated Index yet. MySQL should be able to use the Data of the new Index to find out, which records to show in a Taster way, since less data ist regarded than when the whole table is scanned.

Comment: I tried it as you recommended creating a new index with id, reputation and created_at fields, but unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Did it even try to use the new Index? Perhaps try first using a smaller select list so that only Columns from the Index are returned. Later you can use the ID to geht the rest. The way to that can be discussed, if the smaller Version helps.

Comment: OK,. I hope it was worth a try. If the DBMS used it and got not faster that's the wrong way. Perhaps the single record itself is already not very long.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from (
  SELECT -- everything is ok here
  , CASE 
      WHEN p.created_at >= unix_timestamp(now() - INTERVAL p.reputation DAY) 
        THEN + p.reputation ELSE NULL END order_col
  FROM posts AS p
  WHERE p.status = 'published' -- the only thing for filter
  LIMIT 0,10 -- limit provided as well
) a
ORDER BY 
    a.order_col desc
    ,a.id DESC
```

Comment: While this is faster, it will have the same result only in very rare cases. What this does is: it takes 10 (random) rows (the inner query), then orders that 10 rows.

Comment: Tried already, but unfortunately did not work, because runs on the same computation  rules.

Answer (score 0):

- Inflate-deflate -- `LEFT JOIN` inflates the number of rows, `GROUP BY` then deflates.  The inflated number of rows is costly.  Instead, focus on getting the ids for the desired rows *before* doing any `JOINing`.  With luck, you can get rid of the `GROUP BY`.
- WP schema -- This is an EAV schema which sucks when it comes to performance and scaling.
- What indexes do you have?  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) for how to improve the meta table.
- Complex `ORDER BY`.  This leads to gathering all the rows (after filtering) before sorting and doing the `LIMIT`.  Rethink the `ORDER BY` clause, if possible.

After you have done what you can with my suggestions, start another Question to continue the refinement.  Be sure to include `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.