# How can I restrict the the result based on the values in the select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, top_tags(u.id) as top_tags, cal_rep(u.id) rep
FROM users 
ORDER BY rep
LIMIT :p,20;
```

`top_tags()` is a function that returns either `NULL` or a comma separated string of user's top three tags. Also `cal_rep()` is another function which returns either `0` or the number of reputation. So query above always returns a list of **all** users. Something like this:

```
+----+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+
| id |   name   |            top_tags           |    rep    |
+----+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+
| 1  | Jack     | HTML,CSS,jQuery               | 3244      |
| 2  | Peter    | SQL-Server,MySQL,Database     | 543       |
| 3  | Martin   | NULL                          | 0         |
+----+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+
```

While I want to omit the users who have `NULL` as their `top_tags` and `0` reputation. So this is the expected result:

```
+----+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+
| id |   name   |            top_tags           |    rep    |
+----+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+
| 1  | Jack     | HTML,CSS,jQuery               | 3244      |
| 2  | Peter    | SQL-Server,MySQL,Database     | 543       |
+----+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same expressions in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, top_tags(u.id) as top_tags, cal_rep(u.id) rep
FROM users 
WHERE top_tags(u.id) IS NOT NULL
  AND cal_rep(u.id) <> 0
ORDER BY rep
LIMIT :p,20;
```

Not sure if you want `AND` or `OR`.

If you don't want to repeat the expressions from the SELECT clause, you can use their aliases in the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, top_tags(u.id) as top_tags, cal_rep(u.id) rep
FROM users 
HAVING top_tags IS NOT NULL
   AND rep <> 0
ORDER BY rep
LIMIT :p,20;
```

Regarding the performance: On a table with a sequence of 1 million integers i have tested the following queries (MySQL 5.7.18):

```
select i
from helper.seq
-- 0.265 sec

select length(sha2(sha2(i, 512), 512)) as l
from helper.seq
-- 1.843 sec

select length(sha2(sha2(i, 512), 512)) as l
from helper.seq
where length(sha2(sha2(i, 512), 512)) = 128
-- 3.437 sec

select length(sha2(sha2(i, 512), 512)) as l
from helper.seq
having l = 128
-- 3.531 sec

select *
from (
    select length(sha2(sha2(i, 512), 512)) as l
    from helper.seq
) sub
where l = 128
-- 3.547 sec
```

Comparing the first two queries, we can see that the nested function call has an overhead of ~ 1.6 seconds. For the other three queries we see the same overhead doubled. I don't know what's going on behind the scenes, but it looks like MySQL will execute the functions twice regardless of the method.

Comment: thank you ... just do you think your first query is optimal? Since you're calling the function twice. Both on the `SELECT` statement and `WHERE` clause ..

Comment: Based on your benchmark, I guess initializing the result of the function into a variable, and using that variable twice in the query would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `WHERE` clause and `is null` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (
  SELECT u.id, u.name, top_tags(u.id) as top_tags, cal_rep(u.id) rep
  FROM users 
  LIMIT :p,20
) a
where a.top_tags is not null 
and   a.rep != 0
ORDER BY a.rep;
```

In this way, functions are executed only one time.

Comment: You've tried the same trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45403564/5563083). This will not work as expected, because you are limiting the result before filtering it.