# Optimizing SQL query with a lot of entries in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to optimize SQL query that has embedded selects:

```
SELECT *
  FROM orders o
    LEFT JOIN alarms a ON o.id = a.order_id
    INNER JOIN order_events o4_ ON o.id = o4_.order_id AND (o4_.event_type_id IN (6, 4, 5, 9))
    LEFT JOIN event_types et ON o4_.event_type_id = et.id
WHERE o.arrival > '2018-01-01'
  AND o.arrival <= '2018-12-31'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM order_events as o_e
    WHERE o_e.order_id = o.id
    AND o_e.event_type_id = 4
  )
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM order_events as o_e
    WHERE o_e.order_id = o.id
    AND o_e.event_type_id = 5
  )
```

The main problem that I have is that I want to exclude orders with order_events type 4, and to keep orders with order_events type 5.

Can someone suggest how to optimize this query?

My order_events is huge (650.000 lines).

Comment: see for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45401307/optimizing-order-by

Comment: why don't you just remove 5 from the IN expression, like: o4_.event_type_id IN (6, 4, 9)

Comment: @ErayBalkanli because it is important for me that it does not show orders that have event_type_id 5. If I remove that from the query it will show orders that has event_type_id 4,6 or 9, but it will not check if it has event_type_id 5.